# Query returning no rows founds

Tags: php, mysql

I developed the form in PHP to search a MySQL database, however no matter how I try it still does not retrieve any results at all. And I cannot find any Syntax errors or other similar issues in the code below,

```
    <?php
    $txtkv=$_POST['txtkv'];
    $cbgen=$_POST['txtgenerator'];
    $cbinsulation=$_POST['txtinsulation'];
    $cbclass=$_POST['txtclass'];
    $cbairinlet=$_POST['txtairInlet'];
    $cbip=$_POST['txtIp'];

    // set database server access variables: 
    $host = "localhost"; 
    $user = "root"; 
    $pass = ""; 
    $db = "nordhavn";

    $connection = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die ("Unable to connect!"); 
    mysql_select_db($db) or die ("Unable to select database!"); 

    $query="SELECT Scania.GensetType, Scania.EngineType, Scania.Engine60Hz, Scania.Alternator,NordhavnGenset.MaxKw,  NordhavnGenset.MaxKva, Scania.PriceEur
    FROM Scania 
    LEFT JOIN NordhavnGenset ON Scania.Alternator=NordhavnGenset.Alternator 
    LEFT JOIN Generator ON Generator.Alternator=Scania.Alternator
    LEFT JOIN Insulation ON Insulation.Insulation=NordhavnGenset.Insulation
    LEFT JOIN Klasse ON Klasse.Klasse=NordhavnGenset.Class
    LEFT JOIN AirInletFilter ON AirInletFilter.AirInletFilter=NordhavnGenset.AirInletFilter
    LEFT JOIN IP ON IP.IP=NordhavnGenset.Ip
    WHERE (NordhavnGenset.MaxKva='".$txtkv."')   and (Generator.Alternator='".$cbgen."')  and (Insulation.Insulation='".$cbinsulation."')  and (Klasse.Klasse='".$cbclass."')  and (AirInletFilter.AirInletFilter='".$cbairinlet."')  and (IP.IP='".$cbip."')";        
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die ("Error in query: $query. ".mysql_error()); 
    $i = 0;
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) { 
          echo "<table cellpadding=10 border=1>
                <tr>
                    <td>    Gense Type (Scania.GensetType)  </td>
                <td>    Engine type (Scania.Enginetype) </td>
                <td>    Engine 60Hz  (Scania.Engine60hz)</td>
                <td>    Alternator (Scania.Alternator and Genrator.Alternator)  </td>   <td>    Max Kw  (NordhavnGenset.MaxKw)  </td>
                    <td>    Max Kva  (NordhavnGenset.MaxKva)</td>
                    <td>    Price Euro (Scania.PriceEur)    </td>
                </tr>";    
          while(($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) !== false) { 
                $i++;
                echo "<tr class=\"d".($i & 1)."\">"; 
                echo "<td>"."<center>".$row[1]."</center>"."</td>";
                echo "<td>"."<center>".$row[2]."</center>"."</td>";
                echo "<td>"."<center>".$row[3]."</center>"."</td>";
                echo "<td>"."<center>".$row[4]."</center>"."</td>"; 
                echo "<td>"."<center>".$row[5]."</center>"."</td>";
                echo "<td>"."<center>".$row[6]."</center>"."</td>";
                echo "<td>"."<center>".$row[7]."</center>"."</td>";
                echo "<td>"."<center>".$row[8]."</center>"."</td>"; 
                echo "<td>"."<center>".$row[9]."</center>"."</td>";
                echo "<td>"."<center>".$row[10]."</center>"."</td>";
                echo "<td>"."<center>".$row[11]."</center>"."</td>";
                echo "</tr>"; 
            } 
                echo "</table>"; 
        }else { 
            echo "No rows found!"; 
        }     
    mysql_free_result($result); 
    mysql_close($connection); 
    ?>
```

Comment: Print the rendered query to the screen, copy/paste into mysql and see what the results are. Debug there to isolate the problem

Comment: MySQL displays the results with NO problem at all

Comment: So debug your script. Print the pertinent variables after the query like `var_dump(mysql_num_rows($result))`, `var_dump(mysql_fetch_row($result))`

Comment: Then mysql isn't returning any data for your query. Either you're selecting the wrong database, have different privileges, or something else. The point of copying/pasting the query into mysql was to eliminate mysql as the point of failure so you should be logging in as the same user, selecting the same database, and running the exact same query. And I don't mean copy/paste from your code.. I mean put something like `die($query)` and copy/paste that with all the rendered variables

Comment: I am sorry what your saying is that to copy the SQL query including the variables as well. Well, I have echo the PHP variables and found that they are Not empty at all. So I guess it comes to the same, because the variables are not affected

Comment: Why not use the handle `$connection` you've already created? Try selecting the DB at least using it? `mysql_select_db($db, $connection)`

Comment: I don't know what that means. Are you refusing to print the rendered query because you individually echoed each variable and verified it?

Comment: @Havelock it doesnt make a difference

Comment: no actually Mike im a bit confused about copying the SQL as-is into MySQL, but ill anyway try to give it a try

Comment: what Mike meant is you should put `die($query)` or `print($query)` after `$query="Select....."` Then copy whatever that's printed out and run it against your database (mysql - phpmyadmin or console) if results are returned

Answer (score 0):

What are you expecting as a result, you seem to have many conditions in there. Search forms should provide many criterias to the user but only use them if the user provided something.

For example, instead of using all criterias at once in one big query, do this:

```
$criterias = array("1=1");
if(isset($_POST['txtkv'])){ $criterias[] = 'NordhavnGenset.MaxKva = "'.mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['txtkv']).'"'; }
if(isset($_POST['cbgen'])){ $criterias[] = 'Generator.Alternator = "'.mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['cbgen']).'"'; }
if(isset($_POST['cbinsulation'])){ $criterias[] = 'Insulation.Insulation = "'.mysql_real_escape_string($cbinsulation).'"'; }
if(isset($_POST['cbclass'])){ $criterias[] = 'Klasse.Klasse = "'.mysql_real_escape_string($cbclass).'"'; }
if(isset($_POST['cbairinlet'])){ $criterias[] = 'AirInletFilter.AirInletFilter = "'.mysql_real_escape_string($cbairinlet).'"'; }
if(isset($_POST['cbip'])){ $criterias[] = 'IP.IP = "'.mysql_real_escape_string($cbip).'"'; }

$query = "
SELECT 
    Scania.GensetType, Scania.EngineType, Scania.Engine60Hz, 
    Scania.Alternator,NordhavnGenset.MaxKw, NordhavnGenset.MaxKva, 
    Scania.PriceEur

FROM 
    Scania 
    LEFT JOIN NordhavnGenset ON Scania.Alternator = NordhavnGenset.Alternator 
    LEFT JOIN Generator ON Generator.Alternator = Scania.Alternator
    LEFT JOIN Insulation ON Insulation.Insulation = NordhavnGenset.Insulation
    LEFT JOIN Klasse ON Klasse.Klasse = NordhavnGenset.Class
    LEFT JOIN AirInletFilter ON AirInletFilter.AirInletFilter = NordhavnGenset.AirInletFilter
    LEFT JOIN IP ON IP.IP = NordhavnGenset.Ip

WHERE 
    ".implode(' AND ', $criterias);

$result = mysql_query($query) or die ("Error in query: $query. ".mysql_error());
```

This will create a full query with only the criterias that you need. Notice that at the top, we CREATE the array of criterias and then fill it will all criterias as we go. We also take time to escape them to secure our input which i didn't see in the original request.

Then, using IMPLODE, we collate all items together in between ANDs to create a list of criterias. The "1=1" is used to prevent an empty WHERE clause in case no criterias are provided but in all cases 1=1 is always true, so it will not filter anything out.

I hope this helps and i hope it really was your problem...

Good luck

Comment: Well now the $result returned after mysql_query() doesnt appear to be empty as earlier. However there are no results displayed, it doesnt even say No Rows as previously